# Why not able to route to HTTPS even after added a valid SSL

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, ssl, wildcard

**Scenario**

I have a domain say aabbccdd.com. I requested SSL certificate from AWS certificate manager and validated. Also added this cert to the domain aabbccdd.com. Everything works perfect with proper encryption.

**Issue**

But now my issue is, that domain have other chains such as aabbccdd.com/hh or aabbccdd.com/yy etc. When I navigate from the main domain aabbccdd.com to aabbccdd.com/hh by clicking the links in aabbccdd.com, it is not loading. But When I specifically type https://aabbccdd.com/hh then able to load successfully with proper SSL encryption. So I tried to request an SSL with wildcard such as aabbccdd.com/*. But such expression is not accepting by AWS. Can someone guide me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Paths are not part of the domain/certificate.

Comment: You only need separate certificates or wildcards for any subdomains you have, eg ```xyz.aabbccdd.com```. As long as your domain has a certificate, it applies to any URL paths under that. Are you getting some SSL related error with your paths? Or do you have these paths separately hosted? If that's the case, what's your AWS setup (load balancers, where your application is hosted etc)?

Comment: @chamal Yes. The domain aabbccdd.com has a valid certificate and I am able to go to that address using https. But the moment, I navigate to different pages from that domain eg: aabbccdd.com/yy, it is not able to connect. It is not showing any SSL error, instead, just not able to connect. I am using an ALB and website is hosted in AWS itself

Comment: you have a timeout, or a routing error that is nowhere related to TLS cert

Comment: I am still trying to debug the issue. Realising that if I explicitly type `https://aabbccdd.com/yy` then I can go into that page with proper encryption. But when I am trying to navigate to `aabbccdd.com/yy` by clicking the navbar link in the main page `aabbccdd.com`, it is not working. Navbar code in my html is as follows `<a class="nav-link head_style" href="yy.php">YY</a>`. Those are relative url that I am giving inside `href`. So cannot explicitly code `https://aabbccdd.com/yy` there. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: @SathyajithBhat Yes. I understand that it has nothing to do with TLS after some checking. So I will remove AWS tag from this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and reading, I realised the issue was due client side `http` request is not redirecting to `https`. To do that, I added a listener in my `ALB` with `http` and port 80. Then modified the default rule to redirect traffic to `https`. Please see the screenshot below

[image]

Now all the pages are loading with SSL encryption.